# Rails habtm checkboxes on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is possible to utilize the habtm checkboxes on create action?

because this:

```
   <%= hidden_field_tag "product[size_ids][]", nil %>
              <% Size.order(:size).each do |size| %>
                <li> <%= check_box_tag "product[size_ids][]", size.id, Product.size_ids.include?(size.id), id: dom_id(size) %>
                <%= label_tag dom_id(size), size.size %>
                </li>
              <% end %>
```

was on update and was working since was brought to create page rails spits out the

> undefined method `size_ids' for #

so, have a way to utilize the habtm on a create action?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're likely dealing with one item, you probably mean:

```
@product.sizes_ids
```

The `Product` model doesn't have a direct association with any sizes, it's only instances of it that do.

Comment: thank's but i did not get what you mean.
is not iterated already?

Comment: Some of the helper functions iterate and generate multiple elements, like `options_for_select` does, but that's not how it works for checkboxes. Are you only allowing unselection here or do you want to present all options to the user?

Comment: to present all options to the user. but, in any case, seems that just on update action that this require the product already created.

Comment: On further reflection I think you've got the right idea here, but you're tripping up on the inclusion logic. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Right, thank you @tadman, i got it. but in why changed to @product.sizes_ids

show this undefined method `sizes_ids' for #<Product:0x007fc4c38dbf28>

Comment: that's i was contesting seems that is only possible to use habtm checkboxes after the object is created

Comment: If you want to do it before then you'll have to dig up all possible sizes, like `Size.pluck(:id)`.

Comment: thank you very much, i did understand it. just use collection_check_boxes and get All sizes.

 <%=p.collection_check_boxes :size_ids, Size.all, :id, :size %>

Answer (score 0):

use collection check boxes getting all of the model with ids exemple:

```
 <%=p.collection_check_boxes :size_ids, Size.all, :id, :size %>
```